# How to gracefully show error in Ecto / Elixir?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Something like `Repo.get!(User, 10)`

Bring a result like:

```
(Ecto.NoResultsError) expected at least one result but got none in query:

from u in Db.User,
  where: u.id == ^10

    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:80: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.one!/4
```

How can I gracefully return something like `{:error, "No Record found"}`

I can use `try do` block however it is frowned upon in Elixir. Or I can use Recursive function method

I thought something like this (doesn't work though, just a concept):

```
def find_user(id) do
  case res = Repo.get!(User, id) do
     Ecto.NoResultsError -> {:error, "not found"}
     _ -> {:ok, res}
   end
end
```

This is not a Phoenix application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Repo.get/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:get/3) and check for `nil`.

```
case Repo.get(User, id) do
  nil -> {:error, :not_found}
  user -> {:ok, user}
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer bu @JayJun is perfectly valid, the [arguably] more idiomatic approach would be to implement a helper, having two different clauses:

```
defp gracefully_handle_get(nil), do: {:error, :not_found}
defp gracefully_handle_get(user), do: {:ok, user}
```

and use it that way:

```
User
|> Repo.get(id)
|> gracefully_handle_get()
```